# A question about prime ideals: If $p=a \cap b$ then $p=a$ or $p=b$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Suppose $p$ a prime ideal. If $p=a \cap b$, $a,b$ ideals. Is it true that we have to have $p=a$ or $p=b$?

Comment: Do you know about co-maximal ideals?

Comment: @Mathematician: I know enough about comaximal ideals to see that they have absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

True. Suppose that $\mathfrak{p}$ is neither $\mathfrak{a}$ nor $\mathfrak{b}$. Pick $x \in \mathfrak{a} \setminus \mathfrak{p}$, $y \in \mathfrak{b} \setminus \mathfrak{p}$. Consider $xy \in \mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{p}$. This implies that $x$ or $y$ must lie in $\mathfrak{p}$, contradiction.

Comment: Simple and clear, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

An ideal $I$ satisfying this condition -- namely that if for ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ of $R$, $I = \mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b} \implies I = \mathfrak{a}$ or $I = \mathfrak{b}$ -- is called **irreducible**.  Irreducible ideals occur in the theory of **primary decomposition**.  For the bare rudiments of this theory, see e.g. Chapter 10 of [my commutative algebra notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf).

A few samples:

> In a PID, an ideal is irreducible iff it is a prime power.

$   $

> Prime ideals are irreducible (the OP's question).

$   $

> In a Noetherian ring, irreducible ideals are primary.

$   $

> A proper ideal in a Noetherian ring is a finite intersection of irreducible ideals.

Combining the last two results one gets Noether's theorem, the basic result on primary decomposition.

Comment: +1, nice answer.  Is there any relation between irreducible ideals and irreducible elements of the ring?

Comment: @Eric: I don't see one.  An ideal in a GCD domain generated by an irreducible element is prime hence irreducible, but even in a PID there are nonprime irreducible ideals.  (Needless to say, the terminology "irreducible ideal" was not my doing!)

Comment: Browsing through §10 of Pete's notes I am once again amazed by the quality of his text.

Answer (score 4):

Since $ab\subset a\cap b$, we see that $ab\subset p$.  Now use the definition of prime to see that $a\subset p$ or $b\subset p$.